# Python3: Continuous variable update within Mainframe

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, tkinter

Basically, I have created a thread which continuously writes a global variable in an infinite loop. Then I have the mainframe which should read and display that variable.

The problem is that once the mainframe runs, it only displays the value of the variable which it read at the time of startup, and does not continuously update itself. How do I get the mainframe to update it's variable values with a specified interval?

The variable in question is called "data":

Notes: if you run the code as is, the "data" variable will be set to none. Adding a "time.sleep(5)" before executing mainframe will allow time to set the variable from the http request, and you will see the data populated.

Thanks for the help!

```
#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from tkinter import *
import time
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import threading
from queue import Queue

data = None

class httpReq(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):

        global data

        while True:
            url = "https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump"
            page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
            data = soup.title.text
            print(data)

x = httpReq()
x.start()

class Example(Frame):

        global data

        def __init__(self, parent):
            Frame.__init__(self, parent)
            self.parent = parent
            self.initUI()

        def initUI(self):
            self.parent.title("Example App")
            self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

            frame1 = Frame(self)
            frame1.pack(fill=X)

            lbl1 = Label(frame1, text="Title Data:", width= 20)
            lbl1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

            lbl2 = Label(frame1, text= data)
            lbl2.pack(fill=X, padx=5, expand=True)

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("600x200")
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save a reference to the label, and then set up a function that updates the label and then arranges for itself to be called again. In the following example the label will be updated once a second.

```
class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ...
        # call this once, after the UI has been initialized
        self.update_data()
    ...
    def initUI(self):
        ...
        # save a reference to the label that shows the data
        self.lbl2 = Label(frame1, text= data)
        self.lbl2.pack(fill=X, padx=5, expand=True)
        ...

    def update_data(self):
        # reset the label
        self.lbl2.configure(text=data)

        # call this function again in one second
        self.lbl2.after(1000, self.update_data)
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan, that worked perfectly! . . . Is there an online resource specific to Tkinter that you would recommend I read up on?